# Pandas set new value based in if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new field in a Pandas dataframe which is the concatenated strings of selected other fields, separated by a comma, but only where a value exists in those other fields.

```
Name City   Food1  Food2  Food3
Dave London cheese ham
Stan Boston eggs   cheese fish      
Jean Paris  fish

Name City   Food1  Food2  Food3  concat
Dave London cheese ham           cheese,ham          
Stan Boston eggs   cheese fish   eggs,cheese,fish
Jean Paris  fish                 fish
```

I could concatenate all fields with
`df[concat'] = df['Food1'] + ',' + df['Food2'] + ',' +  df['Food3'] + ',' +  df['Food4']`

but this does not limit to fields with values.

```
Pseudo code is something like:
columns = [df['Food1'],df['Food2'],df['Food3'],df['Food4']]
mylist = []
for column in columns:
    if column:
        mylist.append(column)
df['concat'] = mylist
```

But to use the df['new field'] =  format, Pandas seems to need this on one line. I use Pandas in a simple way but not so much list comprehensions or numpy. Are those where the solution lies?

Comment: Why does `fish` comes with `eggs` and `cheese`? What is the logic?

Comment: `for column in columns: if column`, what does that mean in your pseudo code?

Comment: @harvpan - apols, type, have corrected

Comment: @Erfan - for each column in my list of columns, if a value exists in that column

Answer (score 0):

### `agg` with `strip` and `replace`

```
(df.filter(like='Food')     # extract Food columns (same as df[['Food1', ...]]) 
   .fillna('')              # fill NaNs with empty string ''
   .agg(','.join, axis=1)   # join strings by comma
   .str.strip(',')          # remove leading and trailing commas
   .str.replace(',+', ',')) # remove repeated commas

0          cheese,ham
1    eggs,cheese,fish
2                fish
dtype: object
```

This will work for 1, 3, or 100 columns that need to be joined. You just have to be smart with how you select them.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** this solution is not expandable if you have many columns, in comparison with cs95's answer.

---

But that said,  for your convenience we can build on your tried solution, by adding an `str.replace` and removing all trailing commas:

```
df['concat'] = (df['Food1'] + ',' + df['Food2'] + ',' + df['Food3']).str.replace('(,+$)', '')
```

---

```
   Name    City   Food1   Food2 Food3            concat
0  Dave  London  cheese     ham              cheese,ham
1  Stan  Boston    eggs  cheese  fish  eggs,cheese,fish
2  Jean   Paris    fish                            fish
```